# sorting nested tuple list

Tags: python, sorting

So, what I am trying to do, is to sort a list with that contains `(num, tuple)` I want to sort it first by the second value of the tuple and if 2 are equal, I want to sort it by the `num(of the first tuple)`.

So lets say I have:

```
l = [(1,(2,3)),(3,(2,1)),(2,(2,1))]
print(l.sort(key=something))
[(2,(2,1)), (3,(2,1)), (1,(2,3))]
```

I have tried:

```
l.sort(key=itemgetter(1,0)
```

Of course it didn't work. Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: I get exactly the result you say you want with `itemgetter`

Answer (score 4):

`operator.itemgetter` works fine:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> l = [(1,(2,3)),(3,(2,1)),(2,(2,1))]
>>> l.sort(key=itemgetter(1,0))
>>> print(l)
[(2, (2, 1)), (3, (2, 1)), (1, (2, 3))]
>>>
```

I think the problem is that you tried to print the result of [`list.sort`](http://docs.python.org/3.2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).  You cannot do this because it is an in-place method (it always returns `None`).

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> l = [(1,(2,3)),(3,(2,1)),(2,(2,1))]
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda t: (t[1][1],t[0]))
[(2, (2, 1)), (3, (2, 1)), (1, (2, 3))]
```

Or:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> sorted(l, key=itemgetter(1,0))
[(2, (2, 1)), (3, (2, 1)), (1, (2, 3))]
```

Answer (score 0):

this works too:

```
l.sort(key=lambda x: x[::-1])
```

Note that list.sort sorts the list in place, so print(l.sort(key=something)) would print None.